# How do I update query two tables and update in one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `candidates` and `candidate_subjects`, for storing candidate details and candidate scores respectively. I want a query to update candidate remark to 'FAIL' if the candidate pass less than 6 subjects. To pass a subject, the candidate sum of `ca_score` and `exam_score` for a subject must be greater than 40.

Below is the query I have written but it is not giving the result expected:

```
UPDATE candidates SET candidates.remark='FAIL' WHERE (select 
    count(candidate_subjects.id) AS total_pass from candidates, 
    candidate_subjects where candidates.id=candidate_subjects.candidate_id 
    and (candidate_subjects.ca_score + candidate_subjects.exam_score) >= 40) < 6
```

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE candidate_subjects (
  id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  candidate_id INT(11),
  exam_type_id INT(10),
  subject_id INT(10),
  ca_score INT(11),
  exam_score INT(6),
  score_grade VARCHAR(10),
  date_created VARCHAR(10),
  date_modified TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO `candidate_subjects` (`id`, `candidate_id`, `exam_type_id`, 
`subject_id`, `ca_score`, `exam_score`, `score_grade`, `date_created`, 
`date_modified`) VALUES
  (1, 2, 1, 32, 22, 61, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (2, 2, 1, 5, 21, 38, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (3, 2, 1, 14, 21, 51, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (4, 2, 1, 1, 19, 34, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (5, 2, 1, 2, 23, 39, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (6, 2, 1, 38, 20, 32, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (7, 2, 1, 53, 24, 47, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
  (8, 4, 1, 32, 19, 61, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (9, 4, 1, 5, 22, 41, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (10, 4, 1, 14, 20, 46, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (11, 4, 1, 1, 23, 37, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (12, 4, 1, 2, 21, 36, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (13, 4, 1, 38, 22, 34, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (14, 4, 1, 53, 24, 52, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
  (15, 5, 1, 32, 20, 62, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:44'),
  (16, 5, 1, 5, 22, 38, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:44');


CREATE TABLE candidates (
  id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  exam_no VARCHAR(15),
  surname VARCHAR(50),
  other_names VARCHAR(100),
  school_id INT(11),
  registration_completed INT(11),
  exam_scores_completed INT(5),
  remark VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO candidates (id, exam_no, surname, other_names, school_id,
registration_completed, exam_scores_completed, remark) VALUES
 (1, '1171052001', 'ABADO', 'MASENENGEN', 1052, 1, '1', ''),
 (2, '1170938001', 'AGBA', 'NGUHER', 938, 1, '1', ''), 
 (3, '1170071001', 'ABEE', 'SESUUR', 71, 1, '1', ''),
 (4, '1170938002', 'AHEN', 'REBECCA DOOSUUN', 938, 1, '1', '');
```

Comment: As a side note, you should use `INNER JOIN` from linking several tables instead of using `WHERE`, it makes the queries more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your candidates according to your criteria and their records exists in `candidate_subjects` you can use below query.

```
UPDATE candidates c
JOIN (select 
    count(id) AS total_pass ,candidate_id
    from candidate_subjects 
    where(ca_score + exam_score) >= 40
    group by candidate_id
     ) a on c.id = a.candidate_id
SET c.remark='FAIL' 
WHERE total_pass < 6
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ca811/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid That's great. How do I handle this? Note subject ID for maths is 2, english is 1. total score is ca_score + exam_score. if total sore  for math is < 40 or english is < 40 remark is 'RESIT'. else if  (math >= 40 and eng >= 40) and  total subject passed >=6  remark is 'PASS' 
                else if (score in math < 40 and score in eng < 40) and total subjects passed < 6 remark is 'FAIL' else if (math > 40 and eng > 40) and total subjects passed < 6 remark is FAIL

Comment: @ali79 Its better if you ask another question with all the details you have along with proper data set

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid I have asked another question as you mentioned. This is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46370028/how-do-i-use-conditions-in-one-table-and-update-record-in-another-table

Comment: @ali79 if this answer fulfills the requirement you can mark it as accepted answer, For the new question i will take a look

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like:

```
UPDATE candidates SET candidates.remark='FAIL' WHERE candidate_id IN (SELECT candidate_id FROM candidate_subject WHERE candidatescorecondition>40 HAVING COUNT(*) > 6);
```

Please run in a dev environment first!

Answer (score 0):

If candidates can be marked as `FAIL` without doing all the exams you can do something like this:

```
update candidates set remark='FAIL'
where id in (
  select candidate_id from candidate_subjects
  where ca_score+exam_score > 40 -- passed subject
  group by candidate_id having count(*)<6
)
```

but if a candidate must have data for at least six subjects in order to be evaluated you need to add an extra condition (so a candidate is not marked as failed if he/she is in the middle of the process):

```
update candidates set remark='FAIL'
where id in (
  select candidate_id from candidate_subjects
  where ca_score+exam_score > 40 -- passed subject
  group by candidate_id having count(*)<6
)
and id in (
  select candidate_id from candidate_subjects
  group by candidate_id having count(*)>=6 -- the candidate has data for at leas 6 subjects
)
```